# OCMock for dispatch_async without callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, ocmock, dispatch-async

I have a method on my view controller that uses dispatch_async. After some time, it calls another method. In my test, I want verify that the followup method gets called.

It appears that most people's advice for dealing with OCMock and dispatch_async is to use XCTestExpectation and call fulfill when the task is complete. However, in my test I have no way of knowing when the task is complete, since the function doesn't have a callback. The result is that the test completes before the task completes, and the verify fails.

Here is a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates my issue:

**View Controller**

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)usesAsyncQueue{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5.0]]; //long running task, e.g. network request
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self usedInAsyncQueue];
        });
    });
}

- (void)usedInAsyncQueue{
    // we want to verify that this is called
}
@end
```

**Test**

```
@implementation ViewControllerTest

- (void)testUsesAsyncQueue {
    ViewController * testViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    id viewControllerMock = OCMPartialMock(testViewController);
    
    OCMExpect([viewControllerMock usedInAsyncQueue]);
    
    [testViewController usesAsyncQueue];
    
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5.1]]; //comment this out and the test fails
    
    OCMVerify([viewControllerMock usedInAsyncQueue]);
}


@end
```

As you can see in my test, if I add a sleep command in the test the code works fine. However, I have no way of knowing how long the delay will be, and I don't want to set it to a safe length of time if in reality it would be shorter. I don't want to set the delay to 5 seconds if sometimes it would only take 0.2 seconds.

Is there a way of catching the call to `usedInAsyncQueue` when it happens instead of waiting a while and then checking?

Comment: Those others are correct - you need to use XCTestExpectation with a timeout and add fulfill in your function, exactly where you have ```// we want to verify...``` you can put something like ```[expectation fulfill];``` to do it

Comment: But that line is in the application code, not in the testing code. How can I even have access to an instance of XCExpectation in there? And wouldn't best practice say that you shouldn't put testing code in your app?

Comment: ... and you need to also add a ```testUsedInAsyncQueue``` to the mock and there you add the fulfill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to stub the method you want to verify, and make it call `fulfill`. In the example in the OP, you would stub the method `usedInAsyncQueue` and make it call `fulfill`. Then you can wait for it to be called and fail the test on a timeout.

Here is the full example test

```
- (void)testUsesAsyncQueue {
    ViewController * testViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    id viewControllerMock = OCMPartialMock(testViewController);
    XCTestExpectation * expectation = [[XCTestExpectation alloc] initWithDescription:@"test"];
    OCMStub([viewControllerMock usedInAsyncQueue]).andDo(^(NSInvocation* invocation){
        [expectation fulfill];
    });
    
    OCMExpect([viewControllerMock usedInAsyncQueue]);
    
    [testViewController usesAsyncQueue];
    
    [self waitForExpectations:@[expectation] timeout:5.1];
    OCMVerify([viewControllerMock usedInAsyncQueue]);
}
```

I ran this example program as well as my original production code, and both work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simplest is as below - then the expectation and its fulfilment are all in the same message.

```
@implementation Test

- ( void ) testSomeFunc
{
    XCTestExpectation * expectation = [[XCTestExpectation alloc] initWithDescription:@"Test"];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^ {
        // Some long task

        // Now done ...
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            // Note this fulfill happens in the test code
            [expectation fulfill];

            // This calls the original code, not the test code
            [self usedInAsyncQueue];
        });
    });

   // Wait for it ...
   [self waitForExpectations:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expectation] timeout:10];
}

@end
```

Alternatively, something like this, where you fulfill inside the message you want to test.

```
@interface Test
@property (nonatomic,strong) XCTextExpectation * expectation;
@end

@implementation Test

- ( void ) testSomeFunc
{
  // Here you need some reference to the expectation as it is fulfilled inside the func itself later
  self.expectation = [[XCTestExpectation alloc] initWithDescription:@"Test"];

  // Some code that eventually calls testFunc async and in a block
  // Note this calls *test*Func, it calls test code
  ...

  // Wait for it as before
}

// This is a test func
- ( void ) testFunc
{
  // Here the fulfill takes place inside test
  [self.expectation fulfill];
  // rest of func
  // here you call the code itself, not the test...
}

@end
```

**EDIT 4**

Here is another alternative using block parameters and your code more or less as is.

**View Controller**

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

// Using a completion block here specifically for testing
// Call this with nil when not testing
- (void)usesAsyncQueue:( void (^)( void ) ) completion {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5.0]]; //long running task, e.g. network request
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if ( completion )
            {
               completion();
            }
            [self usedInAsyncQueue];
        });
    });
}
```

**Test**

```
@implementation ViewControllerTest

- (void)testUsesAsyncQueue {
    ViewController * testViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    id viewControllerMock = OCMPartialMock(testViewController);
    
    XCTestExpectation * expectation = [[XCTestExpectation alloc] initWithDescription:@"Test"];

    // Here we pass a block that will fulfill the expectation    
    [testViewController usesAsyncQueue:^ { expectation.fulfill; }];

    // Wait for it ...
   [self waitForExpectations:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expectation] timeout:10];
}
```

Comment: I think I must be missing something here. What is this supposed to be testing?

Comment: Hi Malachi - this is supposed to verify that the block executes. The block executes async and if I understand you correctly you need to verify in your test that ```usedInAsyncQueue``` is called. This 'simplification' does just that, it fulfills the expectation when that message is called.

Comment: This really just shows where to put the expectation and where to fulfill it. But you could e.g. do it differently and put the fulfill in the ```testUsedInAsyncQueue``` as well, but I think this is simplest as you end up using the ```usedInAsyncQueue``` in stead and the expectation is only local to the message. Does this help / make sense?

Comment: The method I'm testing is usesAsyncQueue. I get that what you have here is a simplification, but I don't understand how your code tests usesAsyncQueue

Comment: The goal is to verify that usedInAsyncQueue is actually used when you call the method usesAsyncQueue. Manually called usedInAsyncQueue seems to defeat the purpose

Comment: Ok - it does not directly test that. However, to simplify, I put the expectation in the message as shown and in that same message, where I still have access to the expectation, also fulfill it. While it is not directly in the ```usedInAsyncQueue``` it is fulfilled asyncly as you call that method.

Comment: Our comments crossed! Note you can either fulfill in ```usedInAsyncQueue``` but that requires a bit of reworking, or you can fulfill whenever you call ```usedInAsyncQueue``` which is what happens here. It is the same. I can either ```fullfill, call x``` or have the fulfill inside x e.g. ```x{ fulfill, rest of x}```.

Comment: The simplification, in stead of changing ```x``` leaves it as is and just fulfill when x is called.

Comment: I'll add the alternative in an edit to show if you fulfill inside x itself.

Comment: `Note you can either fulfill in usedInAsyncQueue but that requires a bit of reworking, or you can fulfill whenever you call usedInAsyncQueue which is what happens here.` I don't see how either of these options are possible. All of this happens in the app code, so I can't write testing code there

Comment: In the first option, you specifically need the reworking because of that - to separate the test and the real code. But in the second option, fulfill when you call, you specifically do not need that, as you call the original, not test, code and you fulfill when you call it. I'll edit a bit more to clarify on this specifically ...

Comment: I see your comments are using the terms "real code" and "test code" but all of it is actually happening in the test code. Unfortunately it looks like none of your examples address my question. I wanted to know if it was possible to detect when a method of my view controller is called inside the test code.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to address your most recent comment where it seems you are unsure of where the real and where the test code goes - my naming based on that comment. That is another topic but it keeps on popping up and is causing the whole response to stray off course. I am merely trying to answer your original question as concisely as possible by showing you where you would put an expectation and a fulfill and a wait. I am not trying to solve the issue of how to write the rest of the test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219991/discussion-between-malachi-holden-and-skaak).

Comment: My suggestion for now is to simply note how the expectation, fulfil and wait works and then try to work that into your code.